# What's the correct syntax in mysql vb.net for update query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

this is my sample code

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myConn = New MySqlConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=itss"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "update itss.announcement set annoMessage = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' where idAnno = 3"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, myConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        myConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        myConn.Dispose()
    End Try
    'strMessage = TextBox1.Text
    Form1.GroupBox1.Select()
    Form1.Activate()
    Form4.Activate()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

when I clicked the button an exception appears saying

**You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 's breakthrough to challenge yesterday's old pattern, and to create tomorrow's n' at line 1**

Comment: This is what comes from not using parameters.  Parameterise your SQL query and it will work as you expect.  Read more here: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `reader = command.ExecuteReader` on `UPDATE` statement with concatenated argument string. You should use `ExecuteNonQuery` with parameterized query like this:

```
myConn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = "update itss.announcement set annoMessage = @message where idAnno = 3"
command = New MySqlCommand(query, myConn)
command.Parameters.Add("@message", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
reader = command.ExecuteNonQuery() ' this is used for UPDATE statement
myConn.Close()
```

NB: `ExecuteReader` used to return query results from `SELECT` statement, i.e. `SELECT * FROM itss.announcement WHERE idAnno = 3`.

Comment: There's an error. it says 'BC30311 Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'MySqlDataReader'.'

Comment: You can't assign `UPDATE` query result (which is an `Integer` as total rows affected value) to `MySqlDataReader` by using `ExecuteReader`. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` and strip out `ExecuteReader` as suggested.